# Chain of GROUP BY TRUNC(date)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a simple table with hourly data and value. I want to compute the average of the daily maximum for each month.
The query seems straight-forward at first :

```
WITH daily_max AS
(
  SELECT TRUNC(the_date, 'DD') as my_day, MAX(value) AS value 
    FROM my_data 
   GROUP by TRUNC(the_date, 'DD')
)
SELECT trunc(my_day, 'MM'), AVG(value) 
FROM daily_max
GROUP BY trunc(my_day, 'MM')
order by 1
;
```

However, I got a lot a "duplicates" in the first column (one for each day):

```
01/01/2017 00:00:00 95
01/01/2017 00:00:00 90
01/01/2017 00:00:00 99
01/01/2017 00:00:00 96
01/01/2017 00:00:00 94
01/01/2017 00:00:00 97
01/01/2017 00:00:00 96
01/01/2017 00:00:00 86
01/01/2017 00:00:00 98
01/01/2017 00:00:00 98

01/02/2017 00:00:00 97
01/02/2017 00:00:00 93
01/02/2017 00:00:00 100
01/02/2017 00:00:00 98
01/02/2017 00:00:00 94
01/02/2017 00:00:00 99
01/02/2017 00:00:00 94
01/02/2017 00:00:00 95
01/02/2017 00:00:00 99
```

The first subquery return the daily maximum as expected.

I suspected a weird behaviour with DATE datatype, but when even when I use the TO_CHAR function on the date, I have the same behaviour. How can an expression present in a GROUP BY statement lead to multiple row with the same value ?

```
with daily_max AS
(
  SELECT TRUNC(the_date, 'DD') as my_day, MAX(value) AS value 
    FROM my_data 
   GROUP by TRUNC(the_date, 'DD')
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(trunc(my_day, 'MM')), AVG(value) 
FROM daily_max
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(trunc(my_day, 'MM'))
order by 1
;
```

To add to my confusion, when I cast the date into timestamp in the first sub-query, the result is what I expect :

```
with daily_max AS
(
  SELECT CAST(TRUNC(the_date , 'DD') AS timestamp) as my_day, MAX(value) AS value 
    FROM my_data 
   GROUP by TRUNC(the_date , 'DD')
)
SELECT trunc(my_day, 'MM') AS the_month, AVG(value) 
FROM daily_max
GROUP BY trunc(my_day, 'MM')
order by 1
;

01/01/2017 00:00:00 94.9
01/02/2017 00:00:00 95.78571428571428571428571428571428571429
01/03/2017 00:00:00 95.38709677419354838709677419354838709677
01/04/2017 00:00:00 94.9
01/05/2017 00:00:00 95.32258064516129032258064516129032258065
01/06/2017 00:00:00 96.46666666666666666666666666666666666667
01/07/2017 00:00:00 96.16129032258064516129032258064516129032
01/08/2017 00:00:00 96.16129032258064516129032258064516129032
01/09/2017 00:00:00 96.13333333333333333333333333333333333333
01/10/2017 00:00:00 95.87096774193548387096774193548387096774
01/11/2017 00:00:00 97.3
01/12/2017 00:00:00 96.90322580645161290322580645161290322581
01/01/2018 00:00:00 96.43478260869565217391304347826086956522
```

I probably miss something stupid, but could anyone explain to me these behaviors?

Query to generate the test table :

```
CREATE TABLE my_data 
AS
SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE - ROWNUM/24, 'HH') as the_date, ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.value(0,100),0) AS value
  FROM DUAL 
  CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366*24
  ;
```

Comment: Your first set of duplicates are not one for each day.

Comment: couldn't meet any issue when after i create my_data as you suggested and tried your first sql.

Comment: Could not replicate this - [Oracle LiveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f5809b7hqdtds9qew8b0bzw5c)

Comment: I can reproduce in 12.1 but not 11.2 or 12.2, so seems to be a bug. Which version and patch level are you on?

Comment: @AlexPoole : Indeed, version 12.1
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Seems to happen with an inline view as well as a CTE, Posisbly bug 20537092; the workaround for that seems to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be [bug 20537092](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=20537092.8); it's reproducible in 12.1.0.2 (using a CTE or an inline view) but on in 11.2.0.4 or 12.2.0.1.

The workaround in that document seems to fix this; running your example after setting

```
alter session set "_optimizer_aggr_groupby_elim"=false;
```

gives a sensible result in a 12.1 session that previously did not:

```
TRUNC(MY_DAY,'MM')  AVG(VALUE)
------------------- ----------
2017-01-01 00:00:00       95.5
2017-02-01 00:00:00 95.6428571
2017-03-01 00:00:00 95.3225806
2017-04-01 00:00:00 95.6666667
2017-05-01 00:00:00 97.0322581
2017-06-01 00:00:00       95.7
2017-07-01 00:00:00 95.0967742
2017-08-01 00:00:00 96.1935484
2017-09-01 00:00:00 94.9333333
2017-10-01 00:00:00         96
2017-11-01 00:00:00 96.9333333
2017-12-01 00:00:00 95.3870968
2018-01-01 00:00:00 95.0434783
```

Rewriting the query to avoid the nested group-by might be more practical - depends how complicated you real one is of course, and whether you can modify relevant sessions or the DB init settings, or patch it.

For your (presumably simplified) example, replacing the inner aggregate/group-by with distinct and an analytic version seems to work, in a fresh session without the workaround applied; it's a bit ugly though and might not be practical for you real situation:

```
WITH daily_max AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(the_date, 'DD') as my_day,
         MAX(value) OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(the_date, 'DD')) AS value
    FROM my_data 
)
SELECT trunc(my_day, 'MM'), AVG(value) 
FROM daily_max
GROUP BY trunc(my_day, 'MM')
order by 1
;
```

And as always, just because it looks like this bug doesn't mean it necessarily is; you might need to raise a service request to get confirmation, particularly before patching.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot explain the behavior your see.  You can try writing the logic differently without the CTE:

```
SELECT TRUNC(my_day, 'MM'), 
       SUM(value) / COUNT(DISTINCT TRUNC(the_date, 'DD'))
FROM my_data
GROUP BY TRUNC(my_day, 'MM')
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Pehaps trunc() does not return a date ...

```
WITH daily_max AS
(
  SELECT  to_date(TRUNC(the_date, 'DD')) as my_day, MAX(value)  AS value 
    FROM jfl_test 
    group by  TRUNC(the_date, 'DD')
)
SELECT trunc(my_day, 'MM'), AVG(value) 
FROM daily_max
GROUP BY trunc(my_day, 'MM')
order by 1
;
```

Comment: [`trunc()` does return a date](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions236.htm#SQLRF06151). Calling `to_date()` on a date is just doing two NLS-based conversion, implicitly form date to string, then explicitly back to a date.